# How to Create Overlay to Search A Page (URL) and Perform an Action

Tags: c#, search

I am working on creating a couple easy programs to get myself started post-school.

Right now I am trying to determine if there is a method using C# to search a webpage (Salesforce page) for specific words/block of words, then perform an action like adding the block to the clipboard.

Basically I am searching for "ref:...:ref", then I want to copy that ref code into the clipboard. This is what I wanted to start with, then play with it a little. I would like to eventually take the ref code and paste it to an email that would be initiated from an email address link on the page (if possible).

Is there a way to create an overlay with a button (I made the button and called it GO!) that will perform the search for the ref code then copy that into the clipboard?

I don't need the code, but knowing it is possible and where to start would help me begin the process of solving the problem.

p.s. I would be willing to attempt this using Java, JS, C++, or C# if one is easier than the others.

Comment: I like that you are thinking big for your first project, but TBH this is a complicated thing you are trying to do.  It's not impossible, but it requires some specialist knowledge.  You could try simpler things like downloading a web page with code and searching the file/string first.  Or perhaps think of some other programming task to do.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to think a little smaller. Thanks for the tip!